# Magento product list view sort by new from/new to

Tags: magento, sorting, product

In my magento store product category grid view, there are two sorting options by now, price and name. I'd like to add on more option: New products. I found tutorials and extensions for date added or date modified, but thats not what I need. Id like to use 'New from date' / 'New to date' to sort them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your attribute is new from the attribute frontend option. For that navigate to your attributes, go to your respective attribute and change the settings for: use for filtering in frontend. Then the attribute will be added in frontend for sorting, see the screenshot (sorry, just german):

[image]

I don't know if that resolves your problem. Otherwise check this extension [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-by-date-1201.html)

Comment: I tried that extension, it uses date added. But I'll try new from attribute frontend option.